# Python Telnet block when i get press a key

Tags: python, telnetlib

I'm using telnetlib python to configure my cisco router , i want to "auto" pass a message of "press a key to continue.." because it gets stuck .Is there a command to do that ?

[image: Image of the issue]

Comment: Once you create telnet instance tn, use ```tn.write('\n')``` or any other char to simulate a key. I guess it will do the job.

Comment: i tried it but i get no result .. i used tn.write(b'\n') because it should be with byte format  .. that's what it displays when i write the command : Telnet(10.62.5.101.23):send b'\n' ,it gets stuck until timed out .

Comment: may be add '\n\r' ? try the combinations

Comment: tn.write('\r\n')

Comment: the same result : Telnet(10.62.5.101.23) : send b'\n\r' .. than timed out

Comment: use it like, first \r and then \n ```tn.write('\r\n')```

Comment: still not working .. the same issue : Telnet(10.62.5.101.23): send b'\n\r'..than timed out (by the way ,i should add (b) in every command i wrote)